# Calling functions after state change occurs in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prop

My question is this. I have two components. First component is an image cropper. Second component is the one that i should display the cropped image.

The problem i'm facing is i can pass the cropped image to my second component but i have to press the button that crops the image and pass to the second component, twice. On the second click only my image is passing to the second component. But i can display the cropped image in the first component only by one click. I think it is happening because in reactjs state changes are not occurring immediately. So how can i fix this.

My approach was to create a `prop` function in the 1st component as `this.props.croppedImage(this.state.preview.img);` here `this.state.preview.img` is the cropped image. And in the 2nd component i'm getting the cropped image by calling the prop function.

My code

**1st component (cropper)**

```
class CropperTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: "beautiful",
            scale: 1,
            preview: null,
       }

        this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);

    }

    handleSave = () => {

        const img = this.editor.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL();

        this.setState({
            preview: {
                img,
                scale: this.state.scale,
            }
        })

        this.props.croppedImage(this.state.preview.img);

    }

    setEditorRef = (editor) => {
        this.editor = editor
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="overlay"></div>

                <div className="crop_div">
                    <AvatarEditor
                        image={this.props.cropImage}
                        ref={this.setEditorRef}
                        width={450}
                        height={450}
                        border={50}
                        color={[255, 255, 255, 0.6]} // RGBA
                        scale={this.state.scale}
                        rotate={0}
                    />
                </div>



                <div className="zoom_slider text_align_center">
                    <input className="crop_btn" type='button' onClick={this.handleSave} value='Save'/>

                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CropperTest;
```

**2nd component**

Here i'm basically doing the following.

```
  <CropperTest  croppedImage = {this.getCroppedImg}/>

    getCroppedImg(img){

            alert("Perfect Storm");
            this.setState({

                previewImg:img

            })

        }
```

Comment: setState accepts a second parameter as a callback function for when the state has been updated. Try it out!

Comment: Also, no need to pre-bind your class methods if you’re declaring them like `method = () => {}`

Comment: @ffxsam thanks but it is not the root of my problem

Comment: Yes. Hence why I made a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 25):

> **I think it is happening because in reactjs state changes are not occurring immediately. So how can i fix this?**

From the [`React#setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate),

**setState(updater, [callback])**

> `setState()` enqueues changes to the component state.
>   The `setState` doesn't immediately update the state. `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback `(setState(updater, callback))`

Call the `this.props.croppedImage` in the `setState` callback.You will get updated values  of component state. In your case its `this.state.preview`

```
this.setState({
  preview: {
    img,
    scale: this.state.scale,
  }
}, () => {
  this.props.croppedImage(this.state.preview.img);
})
```

Answer (score 11):

Callbacks are no longer supported in `setState`.
The best way to go about this is to use a `useEffect` and set the dependency variable to the state variable.

```
useEffect(() => {
   //do operation on state change
},[stateVariable])
```

Comment: Wrong answer, that is class component, not React with Hooks. Answer is not gonna work in given situation.

Comment: If you are still using class components in 2022, it is high time to make the switch. They are pretty much losing support.

Comment: Afaik, there is no other work around for this. So if this helps someone, I am going to let it be.

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm useEffect is the way to go now - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: This is a "thanks" for https://stackoverflow.com/a/70686264/7733418 Isn't it? For that you should use your privileges for voting or commenting.